# How to consume API in ColdFusion 10

Tags: api, web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Can you please help me? I am trying to consume response in my ColdFusion application. Just wanted to try with this fake API before proceeding to the actual one.

I have created a component with two functions inside it. My cfc looks like this:

[photoUploadNew.cfc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITEOM.png)

```
<cfcomponent displayname="test" hint="testing.." output="yes">
    <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" showdebugoutput="true">
    <cffunction name="start" access="public" output="no" returntype="any" description="initialize the component"> 
        <cfset variables.testUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts">
        <cfreturn this> 
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction access="public" output="false" name="testGetReq" displayname="TestGetReq" description="testing" returntype="any"> 
        <cfset variables.testUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts">   
        <cfhttp 
            result="httpResponsetest" 
                url="#variables.testUrl#" 
                timeout="30" 
                method="get"
        >
        <cfhttpparam
                type="header"
                name="Content-Type"
                value="application/json"
        />
    </cfhttp>
        </cfhttp>   
        <cfreturn httpResponsetest> 
    </cffunction>   
</cfcomponent>
```

In my cfm page. I am trying to instantiate this component and print whatever I am getting as a response but I am not able to print anything out there.

```
<cfset testObj = CreateObject("component","usedGear_admin.cfc.photoUploadNew").testGetReq()>
<cfoutput >
    #testObj#
</cfoutput>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What output or error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting nothing/blank in output. Can you please help me to check if the code that I have written is correct or does that have flaws in it or something else that I  can try?

Comment: What does your CFC look like?

Comment: I'm not sure we can provide any help at all unless we're able to see what's in your photoUploadNew.cfc that you've invoked with the CreateObject call.  You need to post more details.

Comment: I dont know why but when I edit the question I can see my cfc code and when I save edits . It goes back to blank.

Comment: <cfcomponent displayname="test" hint="testing.." output="yes">
   <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" showdebugoutput="true">
  <cffunction name="start" access="public" output="no" returntype="any" description="initialize the component"> 
   <cfset variables.testUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts">
   <cfreturn this> 
  </cffunction>

Comment: <cffunction access="public" output="false" name="testGetReq" displayname="TestGetReq" description="testing" returntype="any"> 
   <cfset variables.testUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts">   
   <cfhttp 
    result="httpResponsetest" 
     url="#variables.testUrl#" 
     timeout="30" 
     method="get"
   >
   </cfhttp> 
   <cfreturn httpResponsetest> 
  </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>

Comment: It looks like this, I am not able to put it in questions. @snackboy

Comment: I also tried uploading a screenshot of my cfc, I hope you can see it now.  @CFMLBread

Comment: Just to confirm, the path to your cfc is`usedGear_admin/cfc/photoUploadNew`? And I am not sure why you have a `.start()` at the end of the `createObject`. I am not sure that does anything and may be causing a error. Can you check to see if you are getting to the `cfoutputs`?

Comment: @snackboy  .start() is a name of the method in photoUploadNew.cfc. yes your are correct usedGear_admin/cfc/photoUploadNew is the path to my cfc. I tried removing .start() method but no luck. Nothing is printed when I perform cfoutput. I've attached a screenshot of my cfc, please have a look and  let me know the correct way to do it.

Comment: I just wanted to print data from this sample api  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts  and print it on screen. please do let me know if you are aware of any other way to do it.

Comment: For your testGetReq method, can you just return something like "I'm here" just to make sure the it's actually being called.

Comment: Also, you may want to wrap the code in a <cftry> to output any errors.

Comment: @snackboy tried what you said. I can print I'm here and error I'm getting when I tried <cftry> is  this :      The expression has requested a variable or an intermediate expression result as a simple value. However, the result cannot be converted to a simple value. Simple values are strings, numbers, boolean values, and date/time values. Queries, arrays, and COM objects are examples of complex values.
The most likely cause of the error is that you tried to use a complex value as a simple one. For example, you tried to use a query variable in a cfif tag."

Comment: data I am trying to get is from here https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, you can check it. I also tried adding <cfhttpparam
   type="header"
   name="Content-Type"
   value="application/json"
   /> to my cfc

Comment: I edited your post to reveal the code you added. You need to use "code" formatting on code blocks for it to show up. See [this for more info on it](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Based on the error message, instead of using `<cfoutput>` use `<cfdump var="#testObjFun#">` and remove the first `<cfoutput>` block (or change it to `<cfdump>`).

Comment: @snackboy  yay!!! that worked.... many thanks to you :)

Comment: Nice. Glad I could help!

Comment: [Update] Also, if you're trying to initialize variables when the component is created use the standard function name [init](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-and-using-coldfusion-components/implicit-constructor-for-cfc.html) - not a custom name like `start`.  Then you can use the new operator and invoke the init method automatically like this: `testObj = new usedGear_admin.cfc.photoUploadNew()`` instead of cfobject, which requires calling it explicitly.

Comment: Got you, thank for this information @SOS . I was unaware of this init method, thanks for letting me know. Also , do you know how I can get only the data that I want like if I want to get body, id, title and userId for that entry whose id is equal to 6. Is it possible to get it that way?

Comment: No idea, as it sounds api-specific and we don't even know what api you're using ;-)  Best to open a new question, with more info and links to the API docs.

Comment: You appear to have two closing tags for cfhttp: `</cfhttp>`...

Comment: @SOS I was using a fake online API here  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts  , what if I wanted to create my own, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but that's a very different topic. Best open a new thread for it. SO is 1 topic per thread only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `cfhttp` result wrong here. When we do a `cfhttp` call,

```
<cfhttp
  method="get"
  result="httpResponsetest"
  url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
  timeout="30"
>
</cfhttp>
```

They try the following, you will see `httpResponsetest` has multiple keys. The data provided by API will be present in `httpResponsetest.fileContent`. Also most of the time there is `Mimetype,Responseheader,Statuscode` etc.

```
<cfdump var="#httpResponsetest.fileContent#">
```

Here you can see the data is in JSON format. That means you'll need to deserialize them to be able to use it.

```
<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(httpResponsetest.fileContent)#">
```

You can deserialize it and return from the function. Along with that you'll need to handle the case where API responds with am error.

**[Demo](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=05708fe1-6f04-4ff4-936c-d0b40aacb0cb/1620cf33-749e-423e-8d75-44225ed12394/9a89019b-a3ef-4b6e-9d5d-0709bd8865c1.cfm)**

Comment: Though to rrk's point about available headers, just because you're expecting the response to contain JSON, doesn't mean it will.  Always verify the response statusCode is successful before attempting to do anything with the fileContent, and be prepared to handle unexpected failures.

Comment: Also, read up on [scoping](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-and-using-coldfusion-components/cfc-variables-and-scope.html) and get into the habit of using `local` scoping with function variables.

Comment: @rrk thanks for your answer, that was really helpful. Do you have any idea on how to post the data in same fashion, may be using the same sample API. I will be grateful to you if you can provide the Demo.

Comment: You can see how to post data (using `method="post"`) to the API here.  [Demo](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=9fbe3311-ccca-4944-bbe3-3e554a3dd76c/048baeb9-d58d-44ed-8e57-7e961ec7deb5/8b4bca91-e546-49ed-9707-ba52081406b1.cfm) . Make sure to adjust it based on the API that you are using.

Comment: @rrk Thank you so much!!

Comment: @rrk  do you know how can I get only the data that I want like if I want to get body, id, title and userId for that entry whose id is equal to 6. Is it possible to get it that way?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ this page describes different API endpoints that you can use.  You'll have to try it out on your own.

Comment: ok thankss @rrk. One last question, I was here using fake online API :  jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts  what if I wanted to create my own. Is it possible?